# Why my css button show 'animate' when hover?

Tags: css, hover, jquery-animate, mouseover

I just found out that using CSS for button is better than the old Javascript mouseover. So I thought I'll give a try.

When I put the new code for rollover on the logo. I noticed when you move your mouse on the logo. The logo show "spinning" animate instead of "swapping" the image. I was wondering why it do that?

You can try by look at the link: http://www.streetlightministries.ca/2013 - move your mouse on the logo - you can see what I am talking about.

I hope you will be able to help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a example of what  you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies probably in this CSS definition, which you apply to all `<a>` elements.

```
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
```

Together with the fact, that you are using sprites as images, the change in the part of the sprite, which is shown, is animated with a transition.

To overcome this either specify more detailed, which transitions should be animated or cancel out the transition for your logo using something like this:

```
#logo {
  transition: none;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. I make a change on <a> element. Now it is working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have a 0.5s `transition` for all anchors set in the css. A fix would be

```
#logo {
  transition: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the "transition". In your CSS, remove the transition elements from your anchors. Or, alternatively, add "transition:none" to #logo.

Answer (score 0):

Why use `transition: none`? Just remove it!